# Conditional Access with MAUI mobile

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal

Wondering if anyone has been able to get conditional access to work properly with MAUI mobile app setups using Graph API for authentication.  I am not able to see the application in Entra/Azure AD conditional access. The application is registered in App Registration but all sign in is coming from Graph API vs. Application ID of the mobile app.  Looking for potential guidance.

Utilizing this documentation but looking for more guidance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-authentication-flows